# Update mysql 5.5 to 5.6 on ec2

Tags: mysql, amazon-ec2

**I am getting error while updating the mysql-server using yum.**

```
    sudo yum install mysql-community-libs
    Loaded plugins: priorities, update-motd, upgrade-helper
    395 packages excluded due to repository priority protections
    Resolving Dependencies
    --> Running transaction check
    ---> Package mysql-community-libs.x86_64 0:5.6.17-4.el5 will be installed
    --> Processing Dependency: mysql-community-common = 5.6.17-4.el5 for package: mysql-community-libs-5.6.17-4.el5.x86_64
    --> Running transaction check
    ---> Package mysql-community-common.x86_64 0:5.6.17-4.el5 will be installed
    --> Processing Dependency: mysql = 5.6.17-4.el5 for package: mysql-community-common-5.6.17-4.el5.x86_64
    --> Finished Dependency Resolution

Error: Package: mysql-community-common-5.6.17-4.el5.x86_64 (mysql56-community)
           Requires: mysql = 5.6.17-4.el5
           Installed: mysql55-5.5.36-1.44.amzn1.x86_64 (@amzn-main)
               mysql = 5.5.36-1.44.amzn1
           Available: mysql-5.5-1.6.amzn1.noarch (amzn-main)
               mysql = 5.5-1.6.amzn1
           Available: mysql-community-client-5.6.15-3.el5.i386 (mysql56-community)
               mysql = 5.6.15-3.el5
           Available: mysql-community-client-5.6.16-1.el5.i386 (mysql56-community)
               mysql = 5.6.16-1.el5
           Available: mysql51-5.1.73-3.69.amzn1.x86_64 (amzn-main)
               mysql = 5.1.73-3.69.amzn1
           Available: mysql-community-client-5.6.17-4.el5.i386 (mysql56-community)
               Not found
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

**I also tried getting this list -**

```
sudo yum repolist all | grep "mysql.*-community.*"
mysql-connectors-community/x86_64 MySQL Connectors Community  enabled:       1+1
mysql-connectors-community-source MySQL Connectors Community  disabled
mysql-tools-community/x86_64      MySQL Tools Community       enabled:         6
mysql-tools-community-source      MySQL Tools Community - Sou disabled
mysql55-community/x86_64          MySQL 5.5 Community Server  disabled
mysql55-community-source          MySQL 5.5 Community Server  disabled
mysql56-community/x86_64          MySQL 5.6 Community Server  enabled:      49+2
mysql56-community-source          MySQL 5.6 Community Server  disabled
mysql57-community-dmr/x86_64      MySQL 5.7 Community Server  disabled
mysql57-community-dmr-source      MySQL 5.7 Community Server  disabled
```

**When i try to install i get this -**

```
 yum install mysql-server
Loaded plugins: priorities, update-motd, upgrade-helper
You need to be root to perform this command.
[ec2-user@rtb-e-ml-classifier-01 tmp]$ sudo yum install mysql-server
Loaded plugins: priorities, update-motd, upgrade-helper
amzn-main/latest                                                                                               | 2.1 kB     00:00     
amzn-updates/latest                                                                                            | 2.3 kB     00:00     
mysql-connectors-community/x86_64                                                                              | 2.5 kB     00:00     
mysql-connectors-community/x86_64/primary_db                                                                   | 4.3 kB     00:00     
mysql-tools-community/x86_64                                                                                   | 2.5 kB     00:00     
393 packages excluded due to repository priority protections
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package mysql-server.noarch 0:5.5-1.6.amzn1 will be installed
--> Finished Dependency Resolution

Dependencies Resolved

======================================================================================================================================
 Package                          Arch                       Version                              Repository                     Size
======================================================================================================================================
Installing:
 mysql-server                     noarch                     5.5-1.6.amzn1                        amzn-main                     2.8 k

Transaction Summary
======================================================================================================================================
Install  1 Package

Total download size: 2.8 k
Installed size: 0  
Is this ok [y/d/N]: n
```

**I have tried everything please help me in this! How can i solve those dependencies errors?**

Comment: This is really a question best suited for ServerFault.  By the way, have you considered using RDS?

Answer (score 3):

This is how I got 5.6 installed, YMMV.. I had to remove conflicts between 5.5 and 5.6..

```
sudo yum remove mysql55-libs-5.5.38-1.0.amzn1.x86_64 mysql55-common-5.5.38-1.0.amzn1.x86_64
sudo yum localinstall http://repo.mysql.com/mysql-community-release-el6-5.noarch.rpm -y
sudo yum install mysql-community-server -y
```

Comment: I did this, but now I get this error: Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock'

Comment: same problem as @GiovanneAfonso

Comment: @GiovanneAfonso  @Shide  You need to start mysqld.  `sudo /etc/init.d/mysqld start`

Comment: I found that this is how you start the server,  sudo /sbin/service mysqld start

Answer (score 0):

I updated my rpm packages and removed old sqlserver which solved this problem.